# TFRecord Reads and Memory Usage

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, memory, tfrecord

I have a simple question about reading a TFRecord:

Lets say you have a record which has 10 features - each being large numpy array. When you read the record, are all 10 numpy arrays loaded into memory? or is a feature only loaded into memory with you read that particular feature -- allowing me to read 1 feature and never load the other 9 arrays into memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to load all features present in the TFRecord file into memory.

You can be selective by parsing with a custom feature description: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#reading_a_tfrecord_file